# How to make sure the user only inputs 1s and 0s?

Tags: java, input, binary

I have this loop that keeps the user stuck inputting values until he/she, inputs something valid, in this case it has to be binary numbers that must be the size of a certain type of variable. Nonetheless, I don't know how to make the loop continue in the case that the user inputs a number made up of something different aside from 1s and 0s.

I was thinking of using `string.contains()`, but that cannot account for every number. Here's my loop:

```
while((double)inputStr.length() != table.getNumberOfVariables() || 
                    inputStr.replaceAll("\\D","").length() != inputStr.length() ||
                    Double.parseDouble(inputStr) > 1){
```

This line: `Double.parseDouble(inputStr) > 1` was supposed to accomplish that, but I'm dealing with decimal numbers, so if the input is 10 or 100, they're rendered invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, rather than using `\D` in your regex (anything that's not a digit), you must be more specific: `[^01]` (meaning: anything not a zero or one).

```
while((double)inputStr.length() != table.getNumberOfVariables() || 
       inputStr.replaceAll("[^01]","").length() != inputStr.length() ||
       Double.parseDouble(inputStr) > 1){
```

It doesn't win you a prize for nice code though, because it is hard for the reader of this code to find out what you are doing. It's better to turn what you're doing into a method with a clear name, like:

```
public static boolean containsOnly(String s, String only) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (only.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) == -1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As it happens, the Apache commons-lang3 library has such a method in it: `StringUtils.containsOnly`. They have many methods for String manipulation that are clearer and often much faster than using regexes.

Comment: This seems to have done it, thanks. It also shortened the code, don't need to worry about that last line anymore. I will change that then, it will make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to validate the binary string:

```
    String s = "0101110";
    if (s.matches("[01]++")) {
        System.out.println("ok");
    } else {
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I believe that would work as well. I thought a possessive quantifier was appropriate here.